# In R, get a subset of the data frame where the value in a column are contained in a list

Tags: r, dataframe

For instance, let's say I have a dataframe named `df` with a column `"ID"` of integers and I want to grab the subset of my dataframe in which the value in `"ID"` is in the vector `[123,198,204,245,87,91,921].`

What would the syntax for this be in R?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want the `%in%` function:

```
df <- data.frame(ID=1:1000, STUFF=runif(1000))
df2 <- df[df$ID %in% c(123,198,204,245,87,91,921), ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Plese let me know if it solves your problem.

First, we'll need the **which** function.

> ?which
>
> **Which indices are TRUE?**
>
> Description
>
> Give the TRUE indices of a logical object, allowing for array indices.

```
i <- 1:10

which(i < 5)
```

> 1 2 3 4

We'll also need the %in% operator:

```
?"%in%"
```

> %in% is a more intuitive interface as a binary operator, which
>   returns a logical vector indicating if there is a match or not for its
>   left operand.

```
2 %in% 1:5
```

> TRUE

```
2 %in% 5:10
```

> FALSE

**PUTTING AL TOGETHER**

```
# some starting ids
id <- c(123, 204, 11, 12, 13, 15, 87, 123)

# the df constructed with the ids
df <- data.frame(id)

# the valid ids 
valid.ids <- c(123,198,204,245,87,91,921)

# positions is a logical vector which represent for each element if it's a match or not
positions <- df$id %in% valid.ids

positions
```

> [1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE

```
# BONUS
# we can easily count how many matches we have:
sum(positions)
```

> [1] 4

```
# using the which function we get only the indices 'which' contain TRUE
matched_elements_positions <- which(positions)

matched_elements_positions
```

> 1 2 7 8

```
# last step, we select only the matching rows from our dataframe
df[matched_elements_positions,]
```

> 123 204  87 123